# Reduce the number of log file reads by health check

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have this .NET Health Check:

```
public Task<HealthCheckResult> CheckHealthAsync(
            HealthCheckContext context,
            CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    Regex ConnectedRegex = new Regex(_healthOptions.ConnectedRegex);
    Regex ConnectionRefusedRegex = new Regex(_healthOptions.ConnectionRefusedRegex);
    Regex ErrorRegex = new Regex(_healtOptions.ErrorRegex);
    int ConnectedRegexLine = GetLogLine(ConnectedRegex);
    int ConnectionRefusedRegexLine = GetLogLine(ConnectionRefusedRegex);
    int ErrorRegexLine = GetLogLine(ErrorRegex);
    if ((ConnectionRefusedRegexLine > 0 || ErrorRegexLine > 0) &&
        ConnectedRegexLine <= 0)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(HealthCheckResult.Unhealthy());
    }
        return Task.FromResult(HealthCheckResult.Healthy());
    }
}
```

It takes 3 regex values and finds what line they appear on in a log file.

Here is the method I use to get the line for each.

```
private int GetLogLine(Regex regex)
{
    GetLogFile = DefaultLogFile.GetLogFileName();
    using StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(GetLogFile);
    string line;
    int lineNumber = 0;
    int errorLine = 0;
    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        // Try to match each line against the Regex.
        Match match = regex.Match(line);
        if (match.Success)
        {
            errorLine = lineNumber;
        }
        lineNumber++;
    }
    return errorLine;
}
```

I'm conscious that I'm reading the log file 3 times each time this check is run. Am I able to change my check so that it only has to read the log file once but that it still provides the line numbers to my `CheckHealthAsync` method for the if statements? If so, how can I go about doing this?

Comment: IMHO, health checks shouldn't involve reading your own log. Why are you reading your log? What are you trying to prove? Work out what that is, then write a health check to directly verify that thing.

Comment: I agree Jeremy. I already have checks in place for some of the things I'm trying to find in the logs. This is an order from above though. Has to be done.

Comment: Open the log file, seek to the end, log a new random value, keep reading to the end until it appears? Which you could do in an IHostedService to block startup... still icky though. Every other useful test I can think of should be based on internal state. Logging should be filterable without failing a health check. Sometimes the answer to an order from above is "No".

Comment: Succeeding if you don't find any "Connection Refused" matches just feels wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using Regex Named Groups is working for you?
https://www.regular-expressions.info/refext.html

I did not try it, but mabye this is a option

```
    var match = new Regex(string.Join("|",
    $"(<?{nameof(_healthOptions.ConnectedRegex)}>{_healthOptions.ConnectedRegex})",
    $"(<?{nameof(_healthOptions.ConnectionRefusedRegex)}>{_healthOptions.ConnectionRefusedRegex})",
    $"(<?{nameof(_healtOptions.ErrorRegex)}>{_healtOptions.ErrorRegex)})")).Match("inputstring");

if (match.Success)
{
    if (match.Groups.ContainsKey(nameof(_healthOptions.ConnectedRegex)))
    {

    }
    else if (match.Groups.ContainsKey(nameof(_healthOptions.ConnectionRefusedRegex)))
    {
        
    }
    else if (match.Groups.ContainsKey(nameof(_healthOptions.ErrorRegex)))
    {
        
    }
}
```